# Why is `exists` modifying my constant?

Tags: perl, constants, autovivification

The [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) function can [unexpectedly autovivify entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700069/how-can-i-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-deep-perl-hash) in hashes.

What surprises me is that this behavior carries over to constants as well:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump 'dump';

use constant data => {
                       'foo' => {
                                  'bar' => 'baz',
                                },
                       'a'   => {
                                  'b'   => 'c',
                                }
                     };

dump data;   # Pre-modified

print "No data for 'soda->cola->pop'\n" unless exists data->{soda}{cola}{pop};

dump data;   # data->{soda}{cola} now sprung to life
```

**Output**

> ```
> { a => { b => "c" }, foo => { bar => "baz" } }
> No data for 'soda->cola->pop'
> { a => { b => "c" }, foo => { bar => "baz" }, soda => { cola => {} } }
> ```

I suspect this is a bug. Is this something 5.10.1-specific, or do other versions of Perl behave similarly?

Comment: You can turn off autovivification for any lexical scope using "no [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification)".

Comment: My question was more about the mutable behavior of constants with `exists` rather than how I could avoid it.

Comment: when working with constants, remember that `use constant PI => 3.14` is the same as `sub PI () {3.14}` and  `use constant data => {...}` is `{my $data = {...}; sub data () {$data}}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is documented behaviour. [perldoc constant](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) says:

> Even though a reference may be
>   declared as a constant, the reference
>   may point to data which may be
>   changed, as this code shows.
>
> ```
> use constant ARRAY => [ 1,2,3,4 ];
> print ARRAY->[1];
> ARRAY->[1] = " be changed";
> print ARRAY->[1];
> ```

It's the reference that is constant, not what it refers to.

Comment: Could you explain why Perl throws a `Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment` error for `use constant var => 50; var = 40;`

Comment: Because you're trying to change a constant. And you can't do that. Constants are... well... constant. That's the whole point of them. The scalar value that you store in a constant can't be changed. But when you create a constant from a hash reference (as in your example) it's the reference that is fixed, not the data that you have a reference to. The reference is the scalar value which is stored in the constant.

Comment: Good stuff, wish I could +2 this answer.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use [Readonly](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Readonly) for creating "true" constants.

Constants created using the `constant` pragma are actually [inlinable subroutines](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Constant-Functions). It means that at compile time the appropriate scalar constant is inserted directly in place of some subroutine call. If the constant is a reference, nothing prevents you from changing the data it points to.

Comment: Is a constant hashref a scalar constant?

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question?

Comment: Use something like Data::Lock (part of Attribute::Constant) rather than Readonly.

Comment: @ysth: I think it's a good answer, albeit not one that spells everything out. Once you know that `constant` creates a subroutine that always returns the same value it follows that it's the hash reference it returns that's constant, not the hash itself. Since the hash is mutable, `exists` can trigger autovivification.

Comment: The problem is with constant. It doesn't do what people expect in these cases. When you're using a tool that doesn't do what you need, you find one that does. That's why this answers the real need instead of the stated question.