# Read file into variable in Perl

Tags: perl, filehandle, slurp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to slurp a file into a string in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206661/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-string-in-perl)

Is this code a good way to read the contents of a file into a variable in Perl? It works, but I'm curious if there is a better practice I should be using.

```
open INPUT, "input.txt";
undef $/;
$content = <INPUT>;
close INPUT;
$/ = "\n";
```

Comment: That isn't good code. This is better: `open(my $fh, "< :encoding(UTF-8)", "input.text") || die "can't open input.text: $!"; $content = do { local $/; <$fh> }; close($fh) || die "can't close input.text: $!";`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think common practice is something like this:

```
    my $content;
    open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "cannot open file $filename";
    {
        local $/;
        $content = <$fh>;
    }
    close($fh);
```

Using 3 argument `open` is safer. Using file handle as variable is how it should be used in modern Perl and using `local $/` restores initial value of `$/` on block end, instead of your hardcoded `\n`.

Comment: See http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp/extras/slurp_article.pod

Comment: Can you please explain what is the purpose of `local $/`? It is not google friendly :)

Comment: @MiroslavPopov, `$/` is the same as `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`. [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) documentation covers it. Here specifically it enables the `$content = <$fh>` to read all file, not just its first line.

Comment: @n0rd, tx. `local $/;` is actually `local $/ = undef;`, which cheats `<FH>` to read the complete file. Is it correct? (Perls is not .NET. We have to read the unwritten.)

Answer (score 16):

```
use File::Slurp;
my $content = read_file( 'input.txt' ) ;
```

Comment: I disagree with loading a module merely to open and read a file. Being able to open and read files is too fundamental an operation not to understand very, very well.

Comment: I disagree with endlessly writing the same five lines of code over and over when one plus a module will do.

Comment: It's not even a standard module.  This reduces the code’s portability.

Comment: That's what dependancies in whatever you generate Makefiles from are for.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you're in an environment where installing modules is possible, you may want to use [`IO::All`](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aAll):

```
use IO::All;
my $contents;
io('file.txt') > $contents;
```

Some of the possibilities get a bit crazy, but they can also be quite useful.

Comment: A non-standard module plus an tricksily overloaded `>` operator just to read a file, something every Perl programmer should be able to do in their sleep, seems like it’s going pretty far overboard.

Comment: tchrist, overloading is not the problem, [conflating HTTP with local file access a la PHP's `readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) (we know how abysmal that turned out) is. But why the hating on CPAN modules? They are Perl's advantage, [it's foolish not to play it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3700037#3700066). But even going so far to invent a combat term against them, that can't be good.