# substitute space to 0

Tags: perl, substitution

Using Perl, I just want to substitute the space to 0. Spaces were separated by tab (\t). Thanks in advance! For example:

```
1   2           2       5               4
4   4   4           4               3   
        4   4           1               
    1   5   6       4
```

To

```
1    2    0    0    2    0    5    0    0    0    4
4    4    4    0    0    4    0    0    0    3    0
0    0    4    4    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
0    1    5    6    0    4    0    0    0    0    0
```

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(DATA,"DATA")||die"cannot open the file: $!\n";


while( <DATA> )
  {
  s/(^|    \K)(?!\d)/0/g;
  print;
  }
```

It comes out:

```
1   2           2       5               4
4   4   4           4               3   
0       4   4           1               
0   1   5   6       4
```

Comment: As in a space character? What language is this?

Comment: what is the character between 1 and 2 for example? is it a tab ( \t) ?

Comment: Thanks, Alan Deep.Yes tab (\t).

Comment: Tip: Don't use `DATA`; it's the name of an existing file handle

Comment: Tip: Don't use global variables for your file handles. Use lexical vars (`open(my $DATA, ...)`)

Comment: Please clarify how the space in e.g. `"1   2           2"` is coded. Is it only tabs: `"1\t2\t\t2"` or is there ordinary white space `\x{20}` in there also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split(/\t/, $_, -1);
   for my $field (@fields) {
      $field = 0 if $field eq "";
   }

   say join "\t", @fields;
}
```

It's not clear what you meant by *"the space"*. The above replaces *empty* fields with zero. Chose the most suitable of the following:

- `if $field eq ""` (empty)
- `if $field eq " "` (1 space)
- `if $field =~ /^[ ]+\z/` (1+ spaces)
- `if $field =~ /^[ ]*\z/` (0+ spaces)
- `if $field =~ /^\s+\z/` (1+ whitespace)
- `if $field =~ /^\s*\z/` (0+ whitespace)

Comment: Hello, ikegami, Thank you so much for your great help. It works！

Comment: Added a missing `chomp`.

Comment: Hello, ikegami. I can read through your code. May I ask you a quick question? Why there is "-1" in split (/\t/,$_,-1)?Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's perfect to add chomp! Thank you!

Comment: @yueli Without the (optional) last argument `split` drops all empty trailing fields; when that argument is negative then all fields are returned, empty or not. See documentation: [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Answer (score 2):

Very easy, 
just store the content of the file in the variable $x then find the match and replace:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = "c:\path\to\file.txt";
my $x;
    open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "cannot open file $filename: $!";
    {
        local $/;
        $x= <$fh>;
    }
    close($fh);


$x=~s/(\n )/\n0/g;      #starting zeros
$x=~s/( \n)/ 0\n/g;     #ending zeros
$x=~s/( $)/ 0\n/g;      #last zero if no end line on end of string
$x=~s/(^ )/0/g;         #first zero at beginning of string
$x=~s/(    )/   0/g;    #zeros within the matrix

print $x;
```

Comment: @yueli I never used perl, but i read the docs to answer your question. ``$filename`` should be replaced by `'temp01'`. If temp01 is located in `C:/` then replace $filename with `'C:/temp01'`

Comment: Hello, Alan Deep, Thank you so much for your quick response. I replaced the file temp01. But, it comes out: Global symbol "$temp01" requires explicit package name at alan.pl line 4.
Execution of alan.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @yueli glad to help!

Comment: I was wondering that there may a readin file problem. I try to figure it out.

Comment: @yueli you may post another question for that for this will be out of question topic. (community guidelines)

Comment: but check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087743/read-file-into-variable-in-perl

Comment: Thank you for your link. I replaced the temp01, but the result is the same as the input temp01 file    1 2   2  5    4
4 4 4   4    3 
  4 4   1    
 1 5 6  4

Comment: I edited the answer to correct filehandle path and error handling on die.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thank you!