# How to remove array elements equal to some element in a second array in perl

Tags: perl

Just wonder if I am given two arrays, A and B, how to remove/delete those elements in A that can also be found in B? What is the most efficient way of doing this?

And also, as a special case, if B is the resulting array after `grep` on A, how to do this? Of course, in this case, we can do a `grep` on the negated condition. But is there something like taking a complement of an array with respect to another in perl?

Thank you.

Comment: As a special case, if the two arrays are sorted, you can do a more efficient differencing operation.  But it doesn't seem like that's what you're after.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700037/how-can-i-represent-sets-in-perl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time you are thinking of `found in` you are probably looking for a hash.  In this case, you would create a hash of your B values.  Then you would grep A, checking the hash for each element.

```
my @A = 1..9;
my @B = (2, 4, 6, 8);
my %B = map {$_ => 1} @B;

say join ' ' => grep {not $B{$_}} @A; # 1 3 5 7 9
```

As you can see, perl is not normally maintaining any sort of `found in` table by itself,
so you have to provide one.  The above code could easily be wrapped into a function, but for efficiency, it is best done inline.

Comment: mod +1. The `map` itself is pretty impressive, but the use of `grep` is amazing. It took me a while to realize what it was doing. I was wondering what you were _grepping_ before realizing that you were not actually using `grep` to match the line. If the statement `not $B{$_}` is true (and it will be for all keys not in `%B`), the value of `$_` is kept in the array that the `grep` command returns.

Comment: I like this, but what if I also want to main the order in `@A` after deleting all elements in `@B`? Is there anything in perl like `LinkedHashMap` in java?

Comment: @Qiang Li, His code does maintain the order of the elements in `@A`. (Assuming main = maintain)

Comment: @Qiang Li, Tie::IxHash is one way of creating an ordered associative array (like LinkedHashMap), but I don't see what that has to do with your question or this solution.

Comment: @Zaid: There will not be any autovivification in this case. You should try it before you write your comments. You don't know Perl as much as you expect.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil : You're right, I'm wrong. Comment removed. :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `none`, `all`, `part`, `notall` methods available via [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm). You can perform pretty much any set operation using the methods available in this module.

There's a good tutorial available at [Perl Training Australia](http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2009-04-02.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you ask for most efficient way:

```
my @A = 1..9;
my @B = (2, 4, 6, 8);

my %x;
@x{@B} = ();
my @AminusB = grep !exists $x{$_}, @A;
```

But you will notice difference between mine and [Eric Strom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189416/eric-strom)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522388/how-to-remove-array-elements-equal-to-some-element-in-a-second-array-in-perl/7523254#7523254) only for bigger inputs.

You can find handy this functional approach:

```
sub complementer {
  my %x;
  @x{@_} = ();
  return sub { grep !exists $x{$_}, @_ };
}

my $c = complementer(2, 4, 6, 8);

print join(',', $c->(@$_)), "\n" for [1..9], [2..10], ...;

# you can use it directly of course
print join(' ', complementer(qw(a c e g))->('a'..'h')), "\n";
```

Comment: It's not any more *effective* than the other working solutions (by definition). Maybe you meant *efficient*?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off with the hash, but you could also use [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail). Stealing [Eric Strom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189416/eric-strom)'s example,

```
my @A = 1..9;
my @B = (2, 4, 6, 8);

say join ' ' => grep {not $_ ~~ @B } @A; # 1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: This doesn't scale nearly as well as Eric Strom's. His solution is worst case Θ(A+B), but yours is Θ(A*B)

Answer (score 0):

Again, you're probably better off with the hash, but you could also use [Perl6::Junction](http://p3rl.org/Perl6::Junction). Again stealing [Eric Strom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189416/eric-strom)'s example,

```
use Perl6::Junction qw(none);

my @A = 1..9;
my @B = (2, 4, 6, 8);

say join ' ' => grep {none(@B) == $_} @A; # 1 3 5 7 9
```

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned by [Eric Strom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189416/eric-strom), whenever you need to search for something specific, it's always easier if you have a hash.

Eric has a nicer solution, but can be difficult to understand. I hope mine is easier to understand.

```
# Create a B Hash

my %BHash;
foreach my $element (@B) {
   $BHash{$element} = 1;
}

# Go through @A element by element and delete duplicates

my $index = 0;
foreach my $element (@A) {
   if (exists $BHash{$element}) { 
      splice @A, $index, 1;    #Deletes $A[$index]
      $index = $index + 1;
   }
}
```

In the first loop, we simply create a hash that is keyed by the elements in `@B`.

In the second loop, we go through each element in `@A`, while keeping track of the index in `@A`.

Comment: It fails because it modifies the array over which it iterates. And all that extra complexity deters from its readability.

Comment: @ikegami: Would it make it more readable to copy the array over to a new array, then rename it back to the original one? This is not the way I'd do it. I was trying for readability.

Comment: You should be worrying about making it work, first. `my @C; for my $e (@A) { push @C, $e if !$B{$e}; } @A = @C;` would make it work, but it's a really complicated way to do `@A = grep { !$B{$e} } @A;`.